# Running loops only for specified sets of integers in fortran

Tags: loops, optimization, fortran, compiler-optimization, gfortran

```
        do i=1,n
                s=0
                do l=1,n
                do m=1,n


                    s=s-a(i,l,m)*q0(l)*q0(m)

                end do
                end do


                f0(i)=s-g(i)*q0(i)
        end do
```

This is a part of my code. As I have to run three loops simultaneously within each other, overall execution becomes terribly slow.

The important fact is that, here, the array a(i,l,m) is non zero only for a set of values of a(l,m,n). Below is the code for setting a(i,l,m).

```
do i=1,n
    do l=1,n
        do m=1,n

        if(i.eq.l+m .or. i.eq.-l+m .or. i.eq.l-m) then
        a1=1
        else 
        a1=0
        end if



        if(i+l+m.eq.n+n+2 .or. i-l+m.eq.n+n+2 .or. i+l-m.eq.n+n+2 .or. i-l-m.eq.n+n+2) then
        b1=1
        else
        b1=0
        end if

    a(i,l,m)=(a1-b1)    (!multiplied with some long function, erased for ease of understanding)

end do
    end do
        end do
```

Now, is there any way in fortran to run the loop only for the values of of (i,l,m) for which the a(i,l,m) is non zero?(Non zero sets only matter in the calculations only, as can be seen) It would save a huge amount of time.

Comment: Is there an a priori way to know which for indexes is the array non-zero? If not, you will need an if condition.

Comment: Write it as loops over l&m. For each of the conditions in turn work what what values of i give a non-zero contribution and apply that. No if conditions and O(n^2) unless I have missed something

Comment: Note that in Fortran the first index of an array is the fastest running index, so to gain speed (better cache usage) it might be useful to reorder the loops as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortran, and similary a plethora of other programming languages, have jump statements which allow one to manipulate the loop-iteration beyond the standard loop control. In Fortran, these statements are CYCLE and EXIT:

> **CYCLE statement:** Execution of a loop iteration can be curtailed by executing a CYCLE statement that belongs to the construct
>   **EXIT statement:** The EXIT statement provides one way of terminating a loop, or completing execution of another construct.

Using these construct it is now possible to cycle through loops quickly when the particular index is irrelevant to the computation. In case of the OP, one could do something like:

```
do i=1,n
   s=0
   do l=1,n
      do m=1,n
         if (a(i,l,m) == 0) cycle
         s=s-a(i,l,m)*q0(l)*q0(m)
      end do
   end do
   f0(i)=s-g(i)*q0(i)
end do
```

Of course, you should always take into account that this will remain an O(n^3) problem.

There is however, more information in how you construct your 3d array `a`. Since `a(i,l,m) = a1 - b1` and `a1` and `b1` can only have the values `0` or `1` depending on a condition, then the element `a(i,l,m)` is different from 0 if only 1 of the conditions is satisfied. It is now very easy to check that if the first condition is satisfied:

```
i == l+m .or. i == -l+m .or. i == l-m
```

the second condition is **never** satisfied:

```
i+l+m == 2*n+2 .or. i-l+m == 2*n+2 .or. i+l-m == 2*n+2 .or. i-l-m == 2*n+2
```

So only one of the conditions can be satisfied at the same time. This gives you some extra leverage to speed things up and remove the inner loop making this O(n^2):

```
do i=1,n
  s=0
  do l=1,n
     m=i-l
     if (m > 0 .and. m <= n) s=s-a(i,l,m)*q0(l)*q0(m)
     m=i+l
     if (m > 0 .and. m <= n) s=s-a(i,l,m)*q0(l)*q0(m)
     m=l-i
     if (m > 0 .and. m <= n) s=s-a(i,l,m)*q0(l)*q0(m)
     m=2*n+2-i-l
     if (m > 0 .and. m <= n) s=s-a(i,l,m)*q0(l)*q0(m)
     m=2*n+2-i+l
     if (m > 0 .and. m <= n) s=s-a(i,l,m)*q0(l)*q0(m)
     m=-(2*n+2-i-l)
     if (m > 0 .and. m <= n) s=s-a(i,l,m)*q0(l)*q0(m)
     m=-(2*n+2-i+l)
     if (m > 0 .and. m <= n) s=s-a(i,l,m)*q0(l)*q0(m)
  end do
  f0(i)=s-g(i)*q0(i)
end do
```

Further improvements are for sure still possible.

Comment: Can you elaborate about further improvements, as you said in the last line. Your sughestions made the code faster, but making it more fast will help.

Comment: This is the point where we need to have more knowledge about `q0` (is it an array or a function?) Also, you can clean up the if-conditions further. Example, if you did `m=i-l` you don't need to do anything anymore on `m=l-i`. There is also still the problem here of double-counting. If `i=l`, there is a lot of double counting ongoing, something I forgot in the existing part.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to store all of the a array, you can calculate its elements as and when you need them, and use guards (extra array elements to avoid out of bounds indices) to avoid the if conditions. Here's how you might do it, reducing the problem to O(n^2) and using much less memory. Also note I have provided a complete test program, this makes answering queries much, MUCH easier - please do it yourself in future!

```
ijb@ianbushdesktop ~/work/stack $ cat o3.f90
Program o3

  Implicit None

  Integer, Parameter :: wp = Selected_real_kind( 12, 70 )

  Real( wp ), Dimension( :, :, : ), Allocatable :: a

  Real( wp ), Dimension( : ), Allocatable :: q0, g, f0, s2

  Real( wp ) :: a1, b1
  Real( wp ) :: s

  Integer :: n
  Integer :: start, finish, rate
  Integer :: i, l, m

  Write( *, * ) 'n ?'
  Read ( *, * ) n 

  Allocate( a( 1:n, 1:n, 1:n ) )
  Allocate( q0( 1:n ) )
  Allocate( f0( 1:n ) )
  Allocate(  g( 1:n ) )
  Allocate( s2( -4 * n - 2:4 * n + 2 ) ) ! guards to avoid out of bounds - haven't thought very carefully about
                                         ! what they should be!!

  Call Random_number( q0 )
  Call Random_number( g )

  Call system_clock( start , rate )
  b1 = 0.0_wp
  do i=1,n
     do l=1,n
        do m=1,n

           if(i.eq.l+m .or. i.eq.-l+m .or. i.eq.l-m) then
              a1=1.0_wp
           else 
              a1=0.0_wp
           end if

           if(i+l+m.eq.n+n+2 .or. i-l+m.eq.n+n+2 .or. i+l-m.eq.n+n+2 .or. i-l-m.eq.n+n+2) then
              b1=1.0_wp
           else
              b1=0.0_wp
           end if

           a(i,l,m)=(a1-b1)    !(multiplied with some long function, erased for ease of understanding)

        end do
     end do
  end do
  do i=1,n
     s=0.0_wp
     do l=1,n
        do m=1,n

           s=s-a(i,l,m)*q0(l)*q0(m)

        end do
     end do
     f0(i)=s-g(i)*q0(i)
  end do
  Call system_clock( finish, rate )
  Write( *, * ) 'Sum f0, time: ', Sum( f0 ), Real( finish - start ) / rate

  Call system_clock( start , rate )
  s2 = 0.0_wp
  Do l = 1, n
     Do m = 1, n

        ! First condition
        i = l + m
        a1 = 1.0_wp
        s2( i ) = s2( i ) - a1 * q0( l ) * q0( m )

        ! Second condition
        i = - l + m
        a1 = 1.0_wp
        s2( i ) = s2( i ) - a1 * q0( l ) * q0( m )

        ! Third condition
        i = l - m
        a1 = 1.0_wp
        s2( i ) = s2( i ) - a1 * q0( l ) * q0( m )

        ! Fourth Condition
        i = 2 * n + 2 - l - m
        b1 = 1.0_wp
        s2( i ) = s2( i ) - ( - b1 ) * q0( l ) * q0( m )

        ! Fifth Condition
        i = 2 * n + 2 + l - m
        b1 = 1.0_wp
        s2( i ) = s2( i ) - ( - b1 ) * q0( l ) * q0( m )


        ! Sixth Condition
        i = 2 * n + 2 - l + m
        b1 = 1.0_wp
        s2( i ) = s2( i ) - ( - b1 ) * q0( l ) * q0( m )

        ! Seventh Condition
        i = 2 * n + 2 + l + m
        b1 = 1.0_wp
        s2( i ) = s2( i ) - ( - b1 ) * q0( l ) * q0( m )


     End Do
  End Do
  Do i = 1, n
     f0( i ) = s2( i ) - g( i ) * q0( i )
  End Do
  Call system_clock( finish, rate )
  Write( *, * ) 'Sum f0, time: ', Sum( f0 ), Real( finish - start ) / rate
End Program o3
ijb@ianbushdesktop ~/work/stack $ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (GCC) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ijb@ianbushdesktop ~/work/stack $ gfortran -Wall -Wextra -std=f2008 -fcheck=all -O o3.f90
ijb@ianbushdesktop ~/work/stack $ ./a.out
 n ?
300
 Sum f0, time:   -23660.711846511185       0.446999997    
 Sum f0, time:   -23660.711846511185        1.00000005E-03
ijb@ianbushdesktop ~/work/stack $ gfortran -Wall -Wextra -std=f2008 -O3 o3.f90
ijb@ianbushdesktop ~/work/stack $ ./a.out
 n ?
300
 Sum f0, time:   -21932.467299817898       0.298999995    
 Sum f0, time:   -21932.467299817898        0.00000000    
ijb@ianbushdesktop ~/work/stack $ ./a.out
 n ?
1000
 Sum f0, time:   -238036.00437753636        52.4760017    
 Sum f0, time:   -238036.00437753636        2.00000009E-03
ijb@ianbushdesktop ~/work/stack $
```

Comment: Be aware that `i` is maximal `n` and minimal `0`, in this case it can be `2n`.